# Getting window height issue on tablet

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, tablet

I have stucked in a very critical problem.The problem is stated below.
I have an phonegap application that i am currently running on my phone and tablet browsers.
On orientation change, I have added a listener.When orientation changes I fetch the height of window via JQuery like $(window).height().
It is working perfect on my phone but window height is wrong.It gave height is reverse order means portrait height for landscape and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(MyFunction, 10);
});

function MyFunction(){
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
       //Action block  
}
```

it works to me Try this

$(document).ready is executes when HTML Document is loaded and DOM is ready
but $(window).load is executes when complete page is fully loaded, and including all frames, objects and images as well

Answer (score 0):

I have an quick and best option for this.I have added a time out on the event.The time may vary.I think the problem was due to dispatching of event before actual orientation changed.

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange",function(e) {
    setTimeout("Orientation Changed Actually...",500);
});
```